# resort on a std::vector vs std::insert

Tags: c++, performance, stl, stdvector, erase

I have a sorted `std::vector` of relative small size ( from 5 to 20 elements ).
I used `std::vector` since the data is continuous so I have speed because of cache.
On a specific point I need to remove an element from this `vector`.

I have now a doubt: which is the fastest way to remove this value between the 2 options below?

1. setting that element to 0 and call `sort` to reorder: this has complexity but
   elements are on the same cache line.
2. call `erase` that will copy ( or memcpy who knows?? ) all elements after it 
   of 1 place ( I need to investigate the behind scense of erase ).

Do you know which one is faster?

I think that the same approach could be thought about inserting a new element without hitting the max capacity of the vector.

Regards

AFG

Comment: Why don't you measure and find out?

Comment: Also, I fail to see how sorting (which involves copying) could be faster than just copying.

Comment: ... and the type of the container's element matters too.

Comment: you are making assumptions about cache lines and so on, but I think you're better off profiling it under realistic conditions.

Comment: why not use something that fits this pattern, like an ordered map? they handle this stuff automatically, and on these sizes the overhead of the underlying tree is negligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of elements, you may be able to swap the element with the last one.

```
void Remove( std::vector<Object> &vec, iterator i ) {
    iterator last = vec.end()-1;
    if (i != last)
        std::swap( *i, *last );
    vec.erase( last );
}
```

You mention setting the element to 0. If that means you have pointers, then you may not need the swap:

```
void Remove( std::vector<Object *> &vec, iterator i ) {
    vec[i] = vec.back();
    vec.erase( vec.end()-1 );
}
```

If you do care about the order, then your second option of using using erase() will preserve it and do the minimum amount of work. It will almost certainly be faster than resorting.